# How to sync SVN repository with a remote FTP filesystem

Tags: linux, ftp, filesystems, svn, rsync

I configured a Centos server locally(in-office) which contains a **SVN** repository with a project. Many developers are working on this repository and making changes.

Also I have a remote server which has **FTP** where the Project is being hosted. So I needed to manually upload repository changes to the **FTP** file system.

I've R&D on a syncing method and decided to mount the remote *FTP* file system on top of Centos server and `rsync` the **SVN** repository directory with the **FTP**'s respected project directory.

My problem is, I can't see any project related files or directories in the **SVN** repository.

So how do I get my requirement done? Is there any proper method to achieve my requirement than this? Or am I completely misunderstood the SVN concept? if it is, please let me know to do this?

Comment: JFYI, I,m too lazy to retype it http://stackoverflow.com/a/24459430/960558

Answer (score 3):

You can not rsync repository per se as directory at FS, because at physical layer it doesn't correlate with logical content.

You **must** to get content of repository (better - without SVN-related metadata) as **real tree** on server-side before and rsync **this** tree

Using (any) SVN-client (CLI `svn` may already exist or you have to install it), you'll `svn export` from `file:///` URL of local repository to `SOMEDIR` and can use this `SOMEDIR` for syncing